# Update and Delete Records on SQL Using Textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, sql-update

I want to Update and Delete Records, i'm using a DataGridView and Textbox for the Query, so it doesn't matter from where i delete the record, i just dont know how to do it, Below is the code that i use to Create New Records, so maybe if i modified some things can work for Updating and deleting, but what can it be?, I know it's a simply question, but i just cant remember how to do it

```vb
    Private Sub btnSaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveRecord.Click

    Dim Conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.104,1433;" + "Database=Base1;Uid=Admindb;Password=2016")   
    Dim msg As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult

    msg = "No puede haber ningun campo vacio"

    style = MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or _
       MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly

    title = "Error"

    Dim sql As String = "Insert into Table3 values (@Nombre, @Paterno, @Materno, @Colonia, @Delegacion, @Estado, @Telefono1, @Telefono2, @Telefono3, @Comentario1, @Comentario2, @Comentario3, @Referencia, @Nombres, @Domicilio, @Codigopostal, @Origen)"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, Conn)
    tbConcatenado.Text = tbName.Text + " " + tbPaterno.Text + " " + tbMaterno.Text
    Try
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Paterno", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbMaterno.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Materno", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbPaterno.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Colonia", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbColony.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Delegacion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbDelegacion.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Estado", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbEstado.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefono1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbTel1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefono2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbTel2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefono3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbTel3.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comentario1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbCom1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comentario2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbCom2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comentario3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbCom3.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Referencia", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbReferencia.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombres", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Me.tbConcatenado.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Domicilio", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbAdress.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Codigopostal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Me.tbZipCode.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Origen", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = Me.tbOrigen.Text


        If tbName.Text = "" Or
            tbMaterno.Text = "" Or
            tbPaterno.Text = "" Or
            tbColony.Text = "" Or
            tbDelegacion.Text = "" Or
            tbEstado.Text = "" Or
            tbTel1.Text = "" Or
            tbReferencia.Text = "" Or
            tbAdress.Text = "" Or
            tbZipCode.Text = "" Or
            tbOrigen.Text = "" Then
            response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
        Else

            Conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("New Record Updated")
            Me.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Textboxes have nothing to do with it.  If you want to delete use a DELETE query; to update use an UPDATE query: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: Dude, i know how to Update tables from SQL, but i specified how can i do that using vb.net, updating textbox by textbox, just like the insert that im using, in the VB i use two kinds of query, one is in a DataGridView and the other one is on textbox, i want to update or delete the selected query in the DGV or TB

Comment: It is no different, grasshopper.  Build an UPDATE query supplying the values much like the code already dies.  Execute it.  DELETE is a little different, usually you try to use the ID in the WHERE portion.  Execute it.  Where the data comes from, DGV, textbox, code variable or burning bush is irrelevant.